# Listenerconfigurations in the observation module of magnolia - best practices question

Tags: magnolia

I would like to trigger a custom command that extends `BaseRepositoryCommand` when someone *adds*, *removes* or *changes* a node or property for `mgnl:page`, `mgnl:area` and `mgnl:component` node types.
I was thinking of using the magnolia observation module for this. Do I have to create separate `listenerConfigurations` for each node type and event type? In my case it would be 6 event-types for 3 node-types or 18 different 
`listenerConfigurations`. Does that have implications on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at: `info.magnolia.cms.util.WorkspaceObservingManager`

There you can use the method #registerChangeListener which you can specify the workspace you want to observe as well as the list of node types you wish.

Performance-wise, it should be smooth since it uses directly JCR observation mechanism under its hood.

Comment: No performance issues from the jcr observation side of things, but keep in mind that version store would grow quickly with versioning on every op so make sure you have enough space in the DB. And you might create load by running many versioning ops in parallel if you get system under the load with many editors working concurrently. Better test this scenario once implemented.